# How to search in vim for a value and then use the value to do search and replace in the same line?

Tags: search, vim, replace, vi

I have the following set of lines, where the 1st column is a Scenario name and it's followed by a list of parameters.

I want to use the 1st column value as a value to the parameter scen=, which may be anywhere in the list of parameters.

For example, If I start with:

```
InstallFull server1=solaris10 server2=solaris11 scen= email= disk=
InstallPartial server1=solaris20 server2=solaris21 email= scen= disk=
InstallMinimum server1=solaris30 server2=solaris32 disk= email= scen=
```

I would like to end up with this:

```
InstallFull server1=solaris10 server2=solaris11 scen=InstallFull email= disk=
InstallPartial server1=solaris20 server2=solaris21 email= scen=InstallPartial disk=
InstallMinimum server1=solaris30 server2=solaris32 disk= email= scen=InstallMinimum
```

I used the following search and replace with back-references syntax:

```
:%s/\(.\{-\}\) \(.*\)\(scen=\)\(.*\)/\1 \2 \3\1 \4/gc
```

but I am looking for an easier way.

Maybe there is a way to run multiple commands, where the 1st command saves the search result into a variable and the 2nd command uses the variable to do a search and replace.

I am looking for a VI one-liner command(s), but functions are also welcomed if such one-liners don't exist. :-)

Thanks.

RaamEE

Comment: The `@/` variable contains the last search, so that might be helpful.

Comment: Thank @EvergreenTree. The @/ contains the search regex. I couldn't use in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%s/\v^(\w+).*/\=substitute(getline('.'),'scen=','&'.submatch(1),'g')/
```

this line looks long but easier to understand.

P.s. this line works if your line has multiple target patterns (`scen=` here)

Answer (score 2):

A (shorter) alternative would be `:global` with normal mode commands that yank the first word and then append it after the `scen=` match:

```
:global/scen=/normal! yenEp
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make a macro that looks like this. Place the cursor on the first line, and

```
qq^"ayiw:s:\Vscen=:\= submatch(0) . @a
```

Press enter here. Then

```
jq
```

After that, just hit `@q` with the number of times you want to perform it. If you want to do it 10 times, `10@q`